# Using Flexbox to create a grid on top of a DIV element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

here's the JS fiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/o7nj1mj9/

HTML:

```
<div id="div2">
        <div class = "flex-table"> 1</div>
        <div class = "flex-table"> 2</div>
        <div class = "flex-table"> 3</div>
        <div class = "flex-table"> 4</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
display: flex;
position: relative;
max-width: 1600px;
padding: 15px;
height: 275px;
overflow: visible;
background-color: #84B6C0;
box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
font-family: 'Open Sans';

#div2 {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: row;
justify-content: space-around;
height: 50px;
line-height:30px;
}

.flex-table {
background: tomato;
margin: 5px;
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1.5em;
text-align: center;
height: auto;
flex-grow: 1;
min-width: 25%;
}
```

I'm trying to create a gird of 4 squares on top of the DIV element, "Portfolio." As you can see, I've got 4 squares, but they aren't filling up the whole space of the DIV.

Apologies if the code is messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `#div2 {`, remove `height:50px` and add `width: 100%`

https://jsfiddle.net/o7nj1mj9/1/

Comment: Interesting! That worked, thanks! Can you explain why?

Comment: With the height, you're obviously restricting your div to not take the parent's height. And for the width, the div is not greedy, so, just make it to 100% to inherit all parent width

Comment: Thanks for the explanation

Comment: @scareware **`#div2` is a flex child too**, so you need to set width: xx; or use flex:1; or flex-grow:1; to make it understand to fill entire space .https://jsfiddle.net/o7nj1mj9/2/ :) or just remove dislay:flex on .container and then  height:100%; is needed to fill entire height of .container ... hope this helps to make you understand how flex works  https://jsfiddle.net/o7nj1mj9/3/ (and also to say that width:100%; is not the only way  to solve this :) )